# Dynamically created iframe on button press vanishes immediately on all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-browser

I'm a novice with this stuff so I've probably made a simple mistake, but so far searches have not helped me.

some semi-relevant context: I've discovered that I can access my university timetable directly without having to go through the login process and then navigating Blackboard to the timetable page. I found by a random typo and Chrome's omnibox autofill that it's accessible as it's own page and I can manipulate the day range and week shown and for which student ID I want to show via data in the URL.
As much as this is *probably* a security flaw I'm trying to take advantage of it to make viewing my time table easier (it's painful to view on mobile with it squashed into the middle of another page), so I've made a page that takes some info from form elements (student number and week number), makes a complete URL from it and creates an iframe with that URL.

anyway; I have determined that the form input is not the problem as simply using `document.write()` with the iframe HTML object in it with the generated URL works perfectly fine (but has the other problems of that particular method).

Further, having the javascript simply spawn a basic URL of my own by the same method but with no variables in the address still has the problem.

How I create the iframe on button press:

```js
var divelmnt = document.getElementById("ifgh");
var ifrm=document.createElement("iframe");
ifrm.setAttribute("id", "tableframe");
ifrm.setAttribute("width", "80%");
ifrm.setAttribute("height", "80%");


function refreshIframe() {
 var iurl ='http://isittuesday.tk';

 ifrm.setAttribute("src", iurl);
 divelmnt.appendChild(ifrm);
```

```html
<form method="POST">
 <button onclick="refreshIframe();">Get timetable</button>
</form>
<br>
<div id="ifgh">
</div>
```

The frame exists for a moment or two once the button is pressed, but then vanishes. Completely, with no trace inside of the `<div>` and the console has no messages.

As a control, simply adding an `<iframe>` with a URL written in to the body of the HTML works perfectly fine.

Secondly, as previously stated, `document.write('<iframe src=iurl></iframe>')` instead of `divelmnt.appendChild`works perfectly fine too, except that it clears the rest of the page due to the implicit `document.open` call, and I'd like to keep the rest of the stuff.

For reference, "ifgh" is "iframe goes here". It's 3am, it's the best I could do. 
Also, I will add a child removal snippet along the lines of `divelmnt.removeChild(ifrm)` so I don't get multiple iframes once this all works

I have tested this in Chrome, IE, Edge, and an extremely old version of firefox I happened to have the installer for.

Unsure where to go from here, I've run out of ideas. Thank you, and my apologies for poor formatting and if anything is unclear, tell me and I'll do my best to fix that when I wake up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `button` element inside the form must have a `type="button"` attribute. Otherwise it just submits the form and reload the page. The default is `type="submit"`.

```
<form method="POST">
  <button type="button" onclick="refreshIframe();">Get timetable</button>
</form>
```

Alternatively, just remove the form if you don't have anywhere to submit to.

Comment: Thank you! I'd read somewhere about a common mistake being people causing the page to reload but for the life of me couldn't figure out *why* it would be reloading.
I've also found that I don't need to remove the previously added child for some reason, I assume due to it having the same ID it just overwrites the old element?